# How to override controller action in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, overriding

I want to have multiple sources (domains), and I don't want to add new actions from different sources in the controller.

How can I do that in YII2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OOP

Parent

```
      class parentController extends Controller
     {
      /**
       * @inheritdoc
       */


      public function actionYourAction()
      {
          return $this->render('your_parent_view');
      }
```

extended

```
     class yourController extends parentController
     {
      /**
       * @inheritdoc
       */


      public function actionYourAction()
      {
          return $this->render('your_view');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**CommonController.php**

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;

class CommonController extends Controller
{

    public actionIndex(){
        //Codes
    }

}
```

**UsersController**

```
<?php
use app\controllers\CommonController; //Give correct path here

class UsersController extends CommonController 
{

    public actionIndex(){
        //Codes
    }

}
```